# Making a Nested List from User Input and Outputting to CSV

Tags: python, csv, export-to-csv, nested-lists, python-3.4

I'm a programming newb (using python3 atm) and my first program requires taking 4 user inputs (in an infinite loop with a designated escape character) and ultimately writing them into a CSV file with headers. Either that or have the data write to a new line every 4 cells, which through my 2 days of googling, I haven't been able to figure out how to do.

I got the program to work with taking the input and writing it to the CSV, however it only overwrites the data in the first row with each iteration of the loop.

Here's what I've got so far

```
count = 0
while (1):

    variable1 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
    variable2 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
    variable3 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
    variable4 = str(input('Enter data here: '))

    save = [variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4]
    file = open('file.csv', 'w', newline='')
    csv_write = csv.writer(save, delimiter=',')
    file.close()
    count += 1
```

my problem is understanding (possibly comprehending) how to take the inputs done in each loop iteration and store the data into its own nested list segment. Sorta like

```
save = [[iteration1Variable1,iteration1Variable2,iteration1Variable3,iteration1Variable4],
        [iteration2Variable1,iteration2Variable2,iteration2Variable3,iteration2Variable4]]
```

and then write the nested list to the CSV.

I hope I was able to depict my needs and lack of understanding of this concept well. :\

Comment: `open` the file *once outside* the loop...

Comment: Also - what's the escape character and what's `count` meant to be doing? Seems a bit redundant in your code

Comment: Looking at it now, its extraneous code that can be removed. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

What about...:

```
  count = 0
  f = open('file.csv', 'w')
  w = csv.writer(f)
  allsaves = []
  while True:
      variable1 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
      variable2 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
      variable3 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
      variable4 = str(input('Enter data here: '))

      save = [variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4]
      w.writerow(save)
      allsaves.append(save)
```

Actually you'd **better** have a termination condition to `break` out of the while, otherwise you'll be there a **long** time:-)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution that runs through the loop only twice...

```
import csv

with open('file.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
 csv_write = csv.writer(csvfile)
 count = 0

 while (count<2):
  variable1 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
  variable2 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
  variable3 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
  variable4 = str(input('Enter data here: '))
  csv_write.writerow([variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4])
  count += 1
```